# Extract .ipa from my iphone using osx sierra

Tags: iphone, extract, ipa

How can I extract the .ipa of a specific application present in my iphone using my mac?
Is there an application or a CLI available?
Anyway ? 
A website hosting all .ipa of the app store?

Thank you

Comment: That's unlikely to be possible without the phone being jailbroken. (It's not on topic for Stack Overflow either way.)

Comment: [su] is the most appropriate site that the vote-to-close mechanism offers, but it's worth checking on [apple.se] for non-developer questions related to the Apple ecosystem.